# Where is Windows XP's version of Minesweeper located?

Tags: windows-xp

People have said that it's in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games, but I don't have that directory. (I also don't have C:\mine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your's may be located under C:\Windows\System32\winmine.exe. Check there!

Comment: yup. mine was there. dunno why it isn't in c:\program files though,